# Detect when user clicks on NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos

I have two `NSTableView` objects on a sheet in OS X.  I need to be able to detect when the user clicks on a row in one of the tables, even if it does not trigger a `tableViewSelectionDidChange` notification (i.e. the user clicks on the row that is already selected).  So I suppose I want to know when the table becomes first responder, but I am not sure if that is the solution, nor how to do it.

How can I do this in either Swift or Obj-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, this is accomplished simply by having an @IBAction for the NSTableView, which tells me whenever the table is clicked or the highlight changes to a different row.  This is all I needed -- false alarm.